# How to search for a text file that contains the word "server" in Windows Search

Tags: windows

I forgot the location of the server logins that I saved in a .txt file. What is the syntax i should use on File Explorer to search for a text file that contains the word "server?"

Comment: Have you simply tried "server"? It should work. However, have a look at https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/ - it works reliable and has many options.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply type the word `server` in search box at up-right:

[image: windows-search_for_a_word_in_text_files]